# Basic Google Motionchart not working. The issue is in the options settings

Tags: html, google-visualization

This Google Motionchart, based off of Google's example [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/motionchart). When I have my code without any options set i.e.

```
var chart = new google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, {width: 800, height:400});
```

the chart displays as it should.

However, although I followed the example set in the Google documentation and pulled my options from the 'Advanced' tab under the working graph, when I try to add them in  (even before editing) It doesn't work. Full code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['motionchart']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Fruit');
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
    data.addRows([
      ['STAR',  new Date (2012,0,1), 1000,],
      ['STAR', new Date (2012,0,1), 1150,],
      ['STAR', new Date (2013,0,1), 1200,],
      ['STAR',  new Date (2013,6,1), 1220,],
      ['STAR', new Date (2014,6,1), 1300,],
      ['STAR', new Date (2014,6,1), 1370,],
      ['SPTR Index',  new Date (2012,0,1), 1000,],
      ['SPTR Index', new Date (2012,0,1), 1050,],
      ['SPTR Index', new Date (2013,0,1), 1110,],
      ['SPTR Index',  new Date (2013,6,1), 1150,],
      ['SPTR Index', new Date (2014,6,1), 1250,],
      ['SPTR Index', new Date (2014,6,1), 1350,]
    ]);

var chart = new   google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

 var options = {};
 options['state'] =
 '{"xZoomedDataMax":1370,"yLambda":1,"iconType":"BUBBLE","dimensions":{"iconDimensions":["dim0"]},"duration":{"timeUnit":"D","multiplier":1},"time":"2012","orderedByX":false,"yAxisOption":"2","playDuration":15000,"uniColorForNonSelected":false,"showTrails":true,"xAxisOption":"2","yZoomedIn":false,"yZoomedDataMax":1370,"xZoomedDataMin":1000,"colorOption":"_UNIQUE_COLOR","yZoomedDataMin":1000,"iconKeySettings":[{"key":{"dim0":"STAR"},"trailStart":"2012"},{"key":{"dim0":"SPTR Index"},"trailStart":"2012"}],"sizeOption":"_UNISIZE","orderedByY":false,"xLambda":1,"nonSelectedAlpha":0.4,"xZoomedIn":false};';

options['width'] = 600;
options['height'] = 400;
chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas? Maybe I'm overlooking a basic syntax error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra `;` at the end of the state string that needs to be removed:

```
options['state'] = '{..."xZoomedIn":false};';
```

it should be:

```
options['state'] = '{..."xZoomedIn":false}';
```

Also, you have errant commas at the end of every row array you add to your DataTable.  Most browsers will simply ignore them, but IE will throw an error; you should remove them:

```
['STAR',  new Date (2012,0,1), 1000,]
```

should be:

```
['STAR',  new Date (2012,0,1), 1000]
```

Comment: Thanks asgallant. I made those changes, but unfortunately the graph still doesn't display. Any other suggestions? Also, did you just look at the code and notice those problems or is there some sort of HTML tool that can help identify errors? Right now I am just editing in a website area without any sort of editing help.

Comment: That should be sufficient: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/J6hRP/.  You can use tools called linters that will check over your code and alert you to syntax errors and problem spots.  [jshint](jshint.com) is a popular one for javascript, and many IDE's and text editors have jshint plugins available (including jsfiddle - click the jshint button at the top of the jsfiddle link to see a few other places your code can be improved).

Comment: Thanks man it worked. I'm definitely going to use jsfiddle in the future, it was much better to work with.

Comment: Another note for anybody else having problems: Apparently the code can't have blank lines in Wordpress. I changed many things at once so I don't know if it mattered, but it might be needed.